# Why is my axios post returning undefined in my functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm new to Next Js and functional comoponents. I'm trying to retrieve data from /api/retrieve2

```
//this is retrieve page
export default function Retrieve() {
    const onSubmit = async data => {        
        const { user } = await axios.post("/api/retrieve2", data);
        console.log(user) // user here is undefined
        };
    return (...);
}
```

```
//this is retrieve2, inside the API folder
export default async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { data } = await axios.post(myBackendUrl, req.body);
        console.log(data) //this is printing the right data - { email: 'casas@gmail.com', code: '123123' }
        res.json(data);
    } catch (e) {
        res.json({ err: e.message || e });
    }
};
```

What am I missing, is this something about Next? About functional components?

Comment: Maybe user cannot be destructured from the returned data. Try posting the response of the api so we can see.

Comment: If the user is inside data, ```const {data: {user}} = await axios.post("/api/retrieve2", data);```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should read about ES6 `destructuring`

You try to destructure `user` but the axios respons witch is a object doesnt contain the key `user`

For `data` it works because there is a data property in the response

Here are all properties that you can destructure:

```
{ data, status, statusText, headers, config, request }
```

Comment: this is how my data looks like - { email: 'casas@gmail.com', code: '123123' }

Comment: your response from the server is always in `data`

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the full URL to make http request to using getInitialProps, here Home is the name of your component

```
const Home = ({ENDPOINT}) => {
   const onSubmit = async data => {        
        const { data } = await axios.post(`${ENDPOINT}/api/retrieve2`, data);
        // consider changing `user` here to `data` since Axios stores response in data object 
        console.log(data) // should be defined
   };

   return (...);

}

Home.getInitialProps = ctx => {
  const ENDPOINT = getEndpoint(ctx.req);
  return { ENDPOINT };
};

// You should store this somewhere you can reuse it
export function getEndpoint(req) {
  return !!req
    ? `${req.headers['x-forwarded-proto']}://${req.headers['x-forwarded-host']}`
    : window.location.origin;
}
```